# is any way to get image data from canvas, drawed from remote video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, youtube

I use html5 video tag to play video.
Then I use canvas element to draw video frame. 
Video is from remote source.
There is no problem to draw frame. But there is problem to get image data from canvas. I want to get image data to make img element or to send data to server for creating image, but it is not possible, because operations with canvas are insecure.
When I use video from same domain, there is no problem.
Only one way, that i have found - is to make script on server, which get remote video and output it, and us this script like source for video element. But it is not very good idea, because it makes additional overload for server.
I am not sure that i have understood properly articles about using "cross-origin"? I think server, where remote video is located, has to send headers like: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" , but if I don't have access to that server, for example I want to user youtube video, there is no ability to execute to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, no, unfortunately.

It can't be done if you don't have access to the remote server to allow cross-origin use, or can ask the administrator of that site (which is very little likely to happen with a site like YouTube).

Generally, you can try to request cross-origin use by supplying the `crossOrigin` attribute:

```
<video ... crossOrigin="anonymous">...</video>
```

If it's allowed you will see data when you get the image data.

## Solutions

One is to copy the video to your own server and stream it from there.

Two, use a proxy server or script as you already tried with your server.

And yes, both cases will impact traffic on your server (and there is a possible legal aspect to this regarding copyright etc.)

Sorry, no way around it.